# Use HTTP/1.0 with .NET HttpListener Class -or- disable range request

Tags: .net, http, http-headers, range, httplistener

I am building a small embedded web server application utilizing the [HttpListener class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34xswsd2.aspx).  When I serve MP3 (`audio/mpeg`) documents to Chrome (and other players), often times a handful of requests are fired off, containing `Range:` headers.  I assume this is to support seeking of the media.

I do not wish to support range requests in my application.  Is it possible to put the `HttpListener` into a mode where it returns `HTTP/1.0` for the protocol, so that user agents will not bother with subsequent range requests?

Alternatively, is there a proper response I can send, indicating to the client that I will not honor a range request?

**Edit:**  I just tried the `Accept-Ranges: none` headers (as defined by [the RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)), but the browser made a request with a range header anyway.  Perhaps there is another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that most clients ignore `Accept-Ranges: none` when the server says that it support http 1.1 .

You can set the http version to 1.0 in your [`HttpListenerResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerresponse.protocolversion.aspx) by

```
response.ProtocolVersion = new Version("1.0");
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I'll award the bounty in 22 hours, when I am able.